# Two foreign keys table database relationship

Tags: mysql, database

I got this four tables and i was finding out their relationships with each other but i couldn't figure out how logically and practically the table name PERFITIM connects with any other table. From theory i know it does but how and why it doesn't make any sense to me. Thank you.
[Here  :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S69WG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just to connect one (or more) Punetor with one (or more) Projects.
This is called many-to-many relationship in some terminologies.
(Supposing that the key id's are not unique in Perfitim table, as it seems in the example.)

Comment: Got it just because they are not unique they have many-to-many relationship. So if they where actually unique what would it be ?

Comment: If the pune_id is unique then it means that a Punetor can have only one Project, and if the pro_id is unique then a Project can have only one Punetor. But in both cases it could be better and clearer represented to have the foreign key in their base table.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `PERFITIM` represents a many-to-many relationship between `PUNETOR` and `PROJEKT`.

Both `PUNE_ID` and `PRO_ID` contain duplicate values (e.g. 517 and 1001), meaning neither column alone could be the primary key. That leaves only a composite primary key, which would indicate a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Can i know the logic behind it ? How is it possible when the table PERFITIM  has no attributes it self only tow foreign keys. Why is many-to-many and not one-to-many?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please let me know if you need more information - I'm not sure what you mean by "How is it possible when the table PERFITIM has no attributes it self only tow foreign keys.". Why do you consider a lack of (non-prime) attributes and/or two foreign keys a problem?